# Rewrite rule for multiple files and parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently I got this rewrite rule in my .htaccess to pass the `[value]` in `http://www.site.com/[value]` to `/page?q=[value]`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page?q=$1
```

How can I achive so the following additional rewrites:

`http://www.site.com/foo/1` -> `http://www.site.com/page?param=1`
`http://www.site.com/bar/1` -> `http://www.site.com/page?param2=1`
`http://www.site.com/baz/1` -> `http://www.site.com/page2?param=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding more rewrites in front of old ones since the level is higher the rule should be in front of old ones:

```
RewriteRule ^bar/([1-9])$                  page?param2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^baz/([1-9])$                  page2?param=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([1-9])$     page?param=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$            page?q=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$             page?q=$1  [L]
```